# Groovy doesn't call static getters/setters from script

Tags: groovy

I have a Settings class and a Groovy script that configures it. The settings class is as follows:

```
abstract class Settings extends Script {
  private static String resourceRoot
  static String getResourceRoot() { return resourceRoot } 
  static void setResourceRoot(String root) { resourceRoot = root }

  abstract void apply();

  @Override
  void run() {
    apply()
    return null
  }
}
```

The script I want to use to set the `resourceRoot` property is like this:

```
/* conf/settings.groovy */

@Base Settings settings

println "Running script"

resourceRoot = 'src/test/resources' // Does nothing
```

When I run this file and I can see the "Running script" message, but when I print `Settings.resourceRoot`, I get null.

However, if I explicitly call `setResourceRoot(String)` and `getResourceRoot()` from the script, then everything works as normal.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Just override the setProperty method http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)

Comment: Weird. This works, but why did I have to do that?

Comment: Guess because script bindings (non-declared variables) have higher priority then static members.

Comment: @daggett as it turns out, script bindings are _the only_ priority when using the default `setProperty` method as shown here: https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-script-closure-does-not-modify-field-annotated-variable/ I'll formally answer this question soon.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, calls to `setProperty` within a Script are delegated to the script bindings and not the actual underlying base class. This is the code as per the [Groovy source](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L54):

```
public void setProperty(String property, Object newValue) {
  if ("binding".equals(property))
    setBinding((Binding) newValue);
  else if("metaClass".equals(property))
    setMetaClass((MetaClass)newValue);
  else
    binding.setVariable(property, newValue);
}
```

To solve my issue, I overrode the `setProperty` method with this:

```
  @Override
  void setProperty(String propertyName, Object newValue) {
    metaClass.setProperty(this, propertyName, newValue)
  }
```

And now it works. [Source article.](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-script-closure-does-not-modify-field-annotated-variable/)